# CSS - Change textline in completely visible with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, greasemonkey

I want to change this not completely visible CSS textline.

[not completely visible textline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ht7c.jpg)

**CSS AREA**

```
.searchresult-title {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  line-height: 1.33em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  height: 43px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

**HTML AREA**

```
<div class="searchresult-title"><p>28A.4 Normalverteilung in OpenOffice.org, Wahrscheinlichkeitsdichte, kumulierte Verteilungsfunktion</p></div>
```

**MY CODE**

```
    $('.searchresult-title').css({
   'overflow': 'auto'   
    });
```

Comment: So the result should be the image?

Comment: @lumio no, this should be completely visible textarea. There are two lines now and the third is not visible.

Comment: Remove your `height` or change `height` to `min-height` and it should work

Comment: I tried with hight: auto and min-hight. doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

I can see in the CSS you have added `overflow: hidden;` which should be `auto`first. I can also see that you have made the same through Javascript. So you can directly do that.

Addition to it, you can set `min-height:43px;` which will solve your problem.
1. Height: That defines the height of your text content.
2.min-height: That defines the minimum height of your text content. Once it goes beyond the minimum height; height will automatically increase.If you want a specific height also you can set it but with that add in your CSS class `overflow:auto;` so that it will not go beyond the height but at least text can be visible with a scroll.

If you have already set a height for the parent then it will work accordingly. If you set min-height for child div it won't go beyond parent height.

Also, Have you added `text-overflow: ellipsis;`also? I can see three dots.

Comment: Doesnt work. I tried with 'height': '100px' too, but nothing changes.

Comment: Maybe I should look higher: $('.related-material').appendTo('.searchresult-item'); 
$('.searchresult-item').appendTo('.searchresult-title'); 
$('.searchresult-title').css({
  'height': '100px'
});

Comment: Did you give a height for parent div?

Comment: i have no text-overflow: ellipsis in whole less.css

Comment: I think probably you need to check once the parent div property. I think that has a height set. like 'searchresult-item' or its parent

Comment: No, I didnt. But now I changed in: $('.related-material').appendTo('.searchresult-item'); 
$('.searchresult-item').css({
  'height': 'min-height'
}); 
$('.searchresult-item').appendTo('.searchresult-title'); 
$('.searchresult-title').css({
  'height': 'min-height'
});

Comment: When I insert height to related-material my script doesnt work anymore

Comment: The:: before selector inserts something before the content of each selected element and the same to insert after we use ::after .

Comment: ::before and :: after what property does it have?

Comment: in order to debug, can u share your work so that I can debug? There can be much reasons for what issue we are seeing here.

Comment: can you try once by adding this class to your CSS file?        .searchresult-title {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  line-height: 1.33em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  min-height: 43px;
  width:235px;
  overflow: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

Comment: Thanx a lot for your support ;) I solved the problem with: $(function() {
    $('.searchresult-title').css({
      'height': 'auto'
    });
});